# Selenium network requests - find or compute URL for file out of network request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, m3u8, webautomation

I'm trying to find the URL of a .m3u8 file on a website.
The URL is not in the source code of the page.
It *is* however viewable in the Network-Monitor of Firefox as the page is loaded.
[image]

Where does the address the request is made to come from? Are addresses like these generated out of javascript in the pagesource? (I have no previous experience with javascript)

I want to extract the hostname + file-path to use it in another application.
How can I:

A: Intercept the https-GET-Requests I make to search for the request that has a .m3u8-file as target

B: Generate the request for the URL for the GET-Request out of the pagesource myself

I am using python with selenium. The page requires authentication, which I also perform with Selenium.

Comment: we can't see real page so we can't see how it works and we can't help you. It can send it in different way - in HTML as tag, as variable in Javascript (as plain or encrypted text, directly in HMTL or in external .js file), it can use JavaScript to generate it from different elements, it can get it as Cookies, it can get it from WebSocket or using AJAX (XHR)

Comment: Hmm, I see the problem. Can you give me a pointer on what to look out for? I'd avoid just dumping multiple hundred lines of page source here. Thx for the list of options. I'll do some research on the different parts.

Comment: I have no idea where exactly to search. I can only say: files HTML and JS, and headers in requests/responses. For HTML you could get `driver.page_source` (which is normal string) and use string functions (like `string.find()`) to search some parts from filename (instead of searching full filename).

Comment: Alright. Should someone want to take a look at the source, here is a link to the page I'm trying to get the .m3u8 from: https://tum.cloud.panopto.eu/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=5ccd3590-85a6-4371-8c41-ac5700e90e4a
(this one is not password protected and publicly available, so it should be fine with copyright).
For my CS lecture videos I'd need to sign in, but it's the same page.